# Cant add IdentityServer4 to ASP.NET Framework 4.7.2 API OWIN

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, .net-standard-2.0

I'm trying to setup Identity Server 4 Auth server in ASP.NET Framework 4.7.2 WEB API, but I can't get it working. I'm not able to add appBuilder.UseIdentityServer() in the Startup class.

My understanding is that the IdentityServer4 is compiled as DotNet Standard 2.0 and the ASP.NET Framework 4.7.2 is compatible with DotNet Standard 2.0, so IDS4 should be able to be used inside 4.7.2 project. Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Is it possible to use IdentityServer4 like that?
What am I doing wrong here?

This is my startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var builder = services.AddIdentityServerBuilder()
        .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(
            IdentityServerConfig.GetIdentityResources())
        .AddInMemoryApiResources(IdentityServerConfig.GetApis())
        .AddInMemoryClients(IdentityServerConfig.GetClients());
}

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(httpConfiguration);
        appBuilder.UseWebApi(httpConfiguration);
    }

}
```

Here is a [link](https://github.com/Genata/TestIds4Api472) to my project:

I've been looking for solution for couple of days, but I can't find anytning helpful. Excuse me if I've missed something.

Thanks.

Comment: Idsrv4 is an aspnetcore solution out of the box so Id say use idsrv3 for net framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the question is about .NET Framework, but not ASP.NET version, it is possible to use .NET 4.7.2.
The `TestApi3.csproj` has to look like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Then it should work based on ASP.NET CORE MVC, not MVC 5.