# Validate IdentityServer4 token in Web API (.Net framework)

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, openid, identityserver4

I would like to validate the token generated from IdentityServer in Web API(.Net Framework 4.7.1).

Here is what I've done so far in `Startup.cs` in Web API

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{

    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
    });

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            Authority = "https://localhost:44380/",
            RedirectUri = "http://localhost:4200/auth-callback",
            ClientId = "angular",
            Scope = "api1",
            ResponseType = "code"
        });

}
```

It throws `code challenge required` error.

Due to the design constraint, I will not be able to use the `IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation` and I should use `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` to validate the token.

**Edit**
I was able to get this working in Web API Core. Here is my Startup.cs of Web API Core. But not sure how to do this in Web API .Net Framework. I also tried with `IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation` with below configuration but it throws 401 error

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Authority = "https://localhost:44380",
        RequiredScopes = new[] { "api1" }
    });
}
```

Comment: which token exactly do you want to validate?  Id token, access token, refresh token?

Comment: I am following the https://www.scottbrady91.com/Angular/SPA-Authentiction-using-OpenID-Connect-Angular-CLI-and-oidc-client to validate user with external identity provider using "Authorization Code" flow. So I need to validate the token created in this flow using Web API(.Net framework)

Comment: @DaImTo I was able to get this working in Web API Core and not sure how to achieve it through Web API .Net Framework. Kindly check the edit.

Comment: @d_f please check the edit.

Comment: updated the answer. checked the package myself and committed the working example.

Comment: I didn't get it, why do you refer `IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation` but mark the question with `IdentityServer4` tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Due to the design constraint, I will not be able to use the IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation and I should use UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication to validate the token.

The conclusion is totally wrong. OpenIdConnectAuthentication is for interactive sign-in, not for bearer token validation. You can use [IdentityServer3.Contrib.AccessTokenValidation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityServer3.Contrib.AccessTokenValidation/) instead.

I have prepared a working [repo](https://github.com/dfrunet/SampleClients/tree/master/MVCBearerNuget), for you and more for myself. It targets 4.7.2. Everything's hardcoded, but the only configuration block is in the `startup.cs`

```cs
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new 
    IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Authority = "https://demo.identityserver.io/",
        RequiredScopes = new[] { "api" }
    });
}
```

As you can see, I utilized the public Identityserver instance.

I used curl
To get the token:

```
curl -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=client&client_secret=secret" https://demo.identityserver.io//connect/token
```

And to call my API:

```
curl -v  -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <The token is here>"  http://localhost/MVCBearerNuget/api/TestApi
```

The answer was:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Expires: -1
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Tue, 10 Sep 2019 17:37:08 GMT
< Content-Length: 19
<
["value1","value2"]* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

An alternative is to build the middleware yourself, but the one I targeted is up to date, easy to use and it definitely works.

Comment: If the author says he cant use it then your question should include options for what they can do instead not telling them yes they can.  your answer does not appear to address the question.

Comment: you missed the *Contrib* suffix. that is exactly an upgrade to the recent MS.IdentityModel and MS.Owin libs. I performed that myself couple years ago, but later found that "contrib" in nuget

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24012160)

Comment: @MaartenDev you missed the idea. **the design constraint** is incompatibility of the frozen *IdentityServer3* with *.Net Framework 4.7.1*, so I provided the answer how to avoid the constraint and get the result

Comment: @d_f I tried with IdentityServer3 token validation. But it throws 401 unauthorized error. Updated the question.

Comment: @d_f We are using "Authorization Code" flow. Will that make any difference while validating?

Comment: @Gopi, no, you just need to check that you requested the scope for your api. and you need to be sure that you use access_token and not the identity one

Comment: @Gopi, an alternative (strange but still working) approach is to run ASP.Net Core libraries, as well as the Identity from IdSrv4 generation in IIS and 4.7.x environment. ASP.Net Core libs are netstandard, so they can run with the "full" framework. (just found a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55476744/1426685) in my old ones)

Answer (score 1):

I have used .NET framework 4.6.1 for creating Web API, For Identity Provider, I am using Identity Server 4 (Earlier I used Identity Server 3). Initially I did face a problem, but I came up with this workaround which worked perfectly to me. Note that I am using ClientCredentials grantflow.

I am using the same IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation library for token validation. The trick is to target to Introspection end point. Below is my configuration which worked.

Here is the configuration for Web API, Note that setting setting ValidationMode property is crucial.

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthServerURI"],
            RequiredScopes = new[] { "comp-read", "stats-read" },
            ClientId = "apiname",
            ClientSecret = "apisecret",
            ValidationMode = ValidationMode.ValidationEndpoint,
            EnableValidationResultCache = true
        });
```

This is how the APIResource and Client is configured in my IDP.

```
new ApiResource
            {
                Name = "apiname",
                DisplayName = "Web API",
                Description = "Access to Web API Services",
                ApiSecrets = new List<Secret> {new Secret("apisecret".Sha256())},
                Scopes = new List<Scope> {
                    new Scope("comp-read", "Read access to Comp Db API"),
                    new Scope("stats-read", "Read access to Stats API")
                }
```

This is how one of the client is configured.

```
new Client
            {
                ClientName = "name of the client",
                ClientId = "clientname",
                Enabled = true,
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret> {
                    new Secret("secretforclient".Sha256())
                },
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    "stats-read"
                },
                AccessTokenLifetime = 1000
            }
```

Hopefully this helps. Thanks.